# Azure DevOps queries with date

Tags: azure-devops

When I've creating queries, I have option for to compare date fields with macros, like 'Created Date >= @StartOfDay('-1d')'.
But all the macros that I found there works considering consecutive  days.
I want something that do not consider the weekends and holidays.
Is there something like '@WorkDays("-1d")'.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps queries with date

Agree with Krzysztof.

There is no such feature to exclude the weekends and holidays now. According to the document [Operators and macros supported for each data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-index-quick-ref?view=azure-devops#operators-and-macros-supported-for-each-data-type):

[image]

Azure devops only `@StartOfDay`, `@StartOfWeek`, `@StartOfMonth`, and `@StartOfYear` macros supported on Azure DevOps 2019 Update 1 and later versions.

There is no option to exclude weekends and holidays.

Besides, there is a user voice about it:

[Add option to exclude weekends when setting up Styling rules using the 'Changed Date' field rule criteria](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/376310/add-option-to-exclude-weekends-when-setting-up-a-s.html)

You could vote and add your comments for this feedback.

Hope this helps.